# Inject classloader to custom message interpolator to fetch resource bundles outside classpath

Tags: hibernate-validator

As part of internationalizing quarkus application, I placed resource bundle properties outside build classpath and now I need my custom resourcebundlemessage interpolator to look for bundles outside classpath by providing the classloader value. By default, message interpolator looks for classloader and since it is null, it is picking the default locale resource bundle. Could someone help me how should I inject classloader to custom message interpolator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use a [custom `ResourceBundleLocator`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-resource-bundle-locator):

```java
public class MyResourceBundleLocator implements ResourceBundleLocator {
    @Override
    public ResourceBundle getResourceBundle(Locale locale) {
        // Get the resource bundle from wherever you want.
        // Note that resources are retrieved at runtime,
        // so you can't access the source/build directories here.
        return <your result>;
    }
}
```

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyValidatorFactoryCustomizer implements ValidatorFactoryCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(BaseHibernateValidatorConfiguration<?> configuration) {
        configuration.messageInterpolator(new MyResourceBundleLocator());
    }
}
```